# Nodemailer subject with French special characters

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, ovh

I have a really strange issue with `Nodemailer`. When I send an email with a subject containing special French characters (e.g., "Association créée avec succès"), email is sent but never received. If I send the same subject without special characters ("Association creee avec succes"), everything is fine. 
I am helpless because I did researches and it should work !

I am using Node 8.11 with `Nodemailer 4.6` and the `SMTP` server is hosted by `OVH`.
Thanks and feel free to ask if you need further informations.

Comment: may not be supported. Do you have debug logs? Also if you take a packet capture on port 25, do you see the email leaving the interface with the french accent ?

Comment: Hi ! I check the doc and it seems to be supported that's why my issue is so strange. My logs are very succinct and just show that email has been sent. I did not try with  packet capture yet but when I test with ethereal, everything works as expected and I receive the email even with special chars. So, I'm completely lost !